# Unit testing of DTOs

Tags: java, unit-testing, dto

Is it appropriate and necessary to test getters and setters?

I think they haven't any logic and they can't crash or throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 17):

You should not unit test DTO's getters and setters, unless they contain some complex logic that requires testing.

Comment: If the DTO uses an auto-convert mechanism, like from `ModelMapper` I'm not sure. I had some tests failing because it didn't map everything correctly. Can be annoying to search a tests for its flaws while the problem lies in the dtos.

Answer (score 10):

Using modern tools it's not much of an effort:

```
import static com.google.code.beanmatchers.BeanMatchers.hasValidBeanConstructor;
import static com.google.code.beanmatchers.BeanMatchers.hasValidBeanEquals;
import static com.google.code.beanmatchers.BeanMatchers.hasValidBeanHashCode;
import static com.google.code.beanmatchers.BeanMatchers.hasValidBeanToString;
import static com.google.code.beanmatchers.BeanMatchers.hasValidGettersAndSetters;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.allOf;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class Test {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testFlatFileReaderMetadata_Parameters() throws Exception {

        assertNotNull(new Test());

        assertThat(Test.class, allOf(hasValidBeanConstructor(), hasValidBeanEquals(), hasValidGettersAndSetters(),
                hasValidBeanHashCode(), hasValidBeanToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: and in addition you can use `@ParaterizedTest` with several classes as `@ValueSource`

Answer (score 9):

I'm reading [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) at the moment, and the authors suggest that you don't write test cases for your «value objects» (e.g. DTO's).

Coverage for the coverage's own sake is never good. ["Tests should be meaningful"](http://openmymind.net/2011/2/23/Foundations-of-Programming-2-Chapter-5-Effective-T), as Karl Seguin puts it.

Comment: While I fully agree with "Coverage for the coverage's own sake is never good", this is not what this question is about. Testing a DTO class is not about distrusting _the language_ being able to shuffle the data correctly in and out of it. It's about distrusting future _developers_ being able to maintain the "DTO contract" of the class. By "DTO contract" I mean that "Every getter should always return the latest value supplied to its corresponding setter". "But hey come on! No one will put some "logic" into a DTO and break _that_, will they?" Yes, they will.

Answer (score 2):

If the code for getters and setters is generated, I would assume it is correct. This is a major drawback of not having properties at language level - you have a lot of generated code that is checked-in into source control and should be tested because it screams red in coverage reports.

On the other hand, even a simple getter might be incorrect, for instance due to C&P error:

```
private String foo;
private String bar;

String getFoo() {return foo;}
String getBar() {return foor;}
```

My final thought: getters and setters are implicitly tested when appropriate logic using them is tested. Setter not covered in tests? - probably you are never setting this field and it might be final? Only setter but no getter called? - useless field?

Comment: static code analysis should spot unused fields and all those stuff, no unit test required in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to/forced to unit test getters and setters for a couple of reasons:
1. `Code coverage`
2. `Automated regression testing`

In these cases you could use libraries that generate these junit test cases, or, write a single utility method using generics to set an object, get it back and compare if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't change anything at this string...
--> no complex setter

```
setTest(String test) {
   this.test = test;
}
```

but if you have something like that, it would make sense to test it (because someone could have changed the token e.g.):

```
String token=";";
   setTestTwo(String testTwo) {
   this.testTwo = testTwo + tokenString;
}
```